# Background Audio - Image on Lock Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, background, ios5

There is a way to add an image to the lock screen for Background Audio, along with setting the Track and Artist name. It was also mentioned in a WWDC 2011 video, but nothing specific to go off of. I have looked everywhere in the docs and cannot find it. I know it is an iOS5 only thing, and Spotify's newest version has this feature. Does anyone know where they can point me in the right direction?

Thank You,
Matthew

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an answer I found for you:

> (1) You must handle remote control events.  You can't be the Now
>   Playing app unless you do. (See the [AudioMixer (MixerHost) sample) code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html).)
>
> (2) Set the Now Playing info:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter]; 
infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"my title", MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                                               @"my artist", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                                               nil];
```

> This is independent of whichever API you are using to play audio or
>   video.

Comment: And how do you set the lock screen image?

Comment: Don't forget to `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

Answer (score 3):

as per Michaels answer above, simply append

```
@{MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage ...]]}
```

to the nowPlayingInfo dict

the full options of available keys are ...

```
// MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle
// MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount
// MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber
// MPMediaItemPropertyArtist
// MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork
// MPMediaItemPropertyComposer
// MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount
// MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber
// MPMediaItemPropertyGenre
// MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID
// MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration
// MPMediaItemPropertyTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

To make controls work....

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

return YES;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

[self becomeFirstResponder];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

[self resignFirstResponder];

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {

if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:

[player play];

break;

case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:

[player pause];

break;

case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:

if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {

[player pause];

}

else {

[player play];

}

break;

default:

break;

}

}

}
```

It only works on a real iOS Device, not on the simulator